# Are paypal direct payments supported in australia?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Does paypal direct payment api support transactions between individuals that reside in australia.What countries does it support.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the DoDirectPayment API (Website Payments Pro) is only supported in the US, UK, and Canada.

That said, the PayPal AU page does have an application for it here:  https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_wp-pro-overview-outside

You could always try signing up or just give them a call.  It may be that "Pro" is available in Australia, but only the "Pro Hosted" which is a little different and works in an iframe on your site.